# S3 Bucket Policy to work with CloudFront GetObject and PutObject directly to the bucket using Multer-S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to make a S3 bucket policy that only allows GetObject from CloudFront but able to PutObject directly to the bucket.

Tried with several combinations but none of the worked.
Here is the latest attempt that I tried.

```
With, Block All Public Access: ALL OFF.

Bucket Policy:

{

    "Version": "2012-10-17",

    "Id": "Policy1604429581591",

    "Statement": [

        {

            "Sid": "Stmt1605554261786",

            "Effect": "Allow",

            "Principal": "*",

            "Action": "s3:PutObject",

            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"

        },

        {

            "Sid": "Stmt1605557746418",

            "Effect": "Deny",

            "Principal": "*",

            "Action": "s3:GetObject",

            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"

        },

        {

            "Sid": "Stmt1605557857544",

            "Effect": "Allow",

            "Principal": {

                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:MYCLOUDFRONT"

            },

            "Action": "s3:GetObject",

            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"

        }

    ]

}
```

This allows me to PutObject to the bucket but GetObject using CloudFront URL got access denied.  If I removed

```
{

            "Sid": "Stmt1605557746418",

            "Effect": "Deny",

            "Principal": "*",

            "Action": "s3:GetObject",

            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"

        }
```

I can GetObject from CloudFront as well as from bucket directly.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution of it.
First follow the instructions here to setup CloudFront: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/. Key point is

```
5.    For Restrict Bucket Access, select Yes.
```

I was using Multer-S3 to upload my image files. ACL needs to be set to

```
acl: 'authenticated-read',
```

Also I am using serverSideEncryption, in S3 bucket properties=>Default encryption

```
Default encryption: Enabled
Server-side encryption: Amazon S3 master-key(SSE-S3)
```

Multer-S3 config

```
serverSideEncryption: 'AES256',
```

S3 Bucket permission un-Block all public access and ACL only enables Bucket Owner's permissions.
The final bucket policy I have is:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E36AHAEXL422P3"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1605745908405",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With all above configurations, this allows PubObject from anyone as long as requests have server side encryption with 'AE256'. GetObject requests directly to the bucket will be blocked.  All GetObject requests need to go through CloudFront.